# Elegant way to refer to files in data science project

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, directory-structure

I have spent few recent days to learn how to structure data science project to keep it simple, reusable and pythonic. Sticking to [this guideline](https://drivendata.github.io/cookiecutter-data-science/?#directory-structure) I have created `my_project`. You can see it's structure below.

```
├── README.md          
├── data
│   ├── processed          <-- data files
│   └── raw                            
├── notebooks  
|   └── notebook_1                             
├── setup.py              
|
├── settings.py            <-- settings file   
└── src                
    ├── __init__.py    
    │
    └── data           
        └── get_data.py    <-- script
```

I defined a function that loads data from `.data/processed`. I want to use this function in other scripts and also in jupyter notebooks located in .notebooks.

```
def data_sample(code=None):
    df = pd.read_parquet('../../data/processed/my_data')
    if not code:
        code = random.choice(df.code.unique())
    df = df[df.code == code].sort_values('Date')
    return df
```

Obviously this function won't work anywhere unless I run it directly in the script where it is defined. 
My idea was to create `settings.py` where I'd declare:

```
from os.path import join, dirname

DATA_DIR = join(dirname(__file__), 'data', 'processed')
```

So now I can write:

```
from my_project import settings
import os

def data_sample(code=None):
    file_path = os.path.join(settings.DATA_DIR, 'my_data')
    df = pd.read_parquet(file_path)
    if not code:
        code = random.choice(df.code.unique())
    df = df[df.code == code].sort_values('Date')
    return df
```

**Questions:**

1. Is this common practice to refer to files in this way? `settings.DATA_DIR` looks kinda ugly.
2. Is this at all how `settings.py` should be used? And should it be placed in this directory? I have seen it in different spot in this [repo](https://github.com/rafacarrascosa/samr) under `.samr/settings.py`

I understand that there might not be 'one right answer', I just try to find logical, elegant way of handling these things.

Comment: Please don’t use a question post as a place to put comments. Stack Overflow is not like a forum; we want to build questions and their answers, so future visitors can quickly see if they have the same problem and the answer(s) would apply to their situation too. They won’t care about how the process eventually arrived at those answers; the conversation about answers should be kept to comments instead.

Comment: Roger that, I'll stick to it in future questions.

Comment: Additional resources on packaging and projects layout I found useful: 
https://realpython.com/python-application-layouts/
https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/05/25/python-packaging/#the-structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm maintaining a economics data project based on DataDriven Cookiecutter, which I feel is a great template.

Separating you data folders and code seems as an advantage to me, allowing to treat your work as directed flow of tranformations (a ['DAG'](https://drivendata.github.io/cookiecutter-data-science/#analysis-is-a-dag)), starting with immutable intiial data, and going to interim and final results.

Initially, I reviewed [`pkg_resources`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html), but declined using it (long syntax and short of understanding cretaing a package) in favour of own helper functions/classes that navigate through directory.

Essentially, the helpers do two things

1. Persist project root folder and some other paths in constansts:

```
# shorter version 
ROOT = Path(__file__).parents[3]

# longer version
def find_repo_root():
    """Returns root folder for repository.
    Current file is assumed to be:
        <repo_root>/src/kep/helper/<this file>.py
    """
    levels_up = 3
    return Path(__file__).parents[levels_up]

ROOT = find_repo_root()
DATA_FOLDER = ROOT / 'data' 
UNPACK_RAR_EXE = str(ROOT / 'bin' / 'UnRAR.exe')
XL_PATH = str(ROOT / 'output' / 'kep.xlsx')
```

This is similar to what you do with `DATA_DIR`. A possible weak point is that here I
manually hardcode the relative location of helper file in relation to project root. If the helper file location is moved, this needs to be adjusted. But hey, this the same way it is done in [Django](https://github.com/deis/example-python-django/blob/master/helloworld/settings.py#L15-L16).

2. Allow access to specific data in `raw`, `interim` and `processed` folders.

This can be a simple function returning a full path by a filename in a folder, for example:

```
def interim(filename):
    """Return path for *filename* in 'data/interim folder'."""
    return str(ROOT / 'data' / 'interim' / filename)
```

In my project I have year-month subfolders for `interim` and `processed` directories and I address data by year, month and sometimes frequency. For this data structure I have 
`InterimCSV` and `ProcessedCSV` classes that give reference specific paths, like:

```
from . helper import ProcessedCSV, InterimCSV
 # somewhere in code
 csv_text = InterimCSV(self.year, self.month).text()
 # later in code
 path = ProcessedCSV(2018,4).path(freq='q')
```

The code for helper [is here](https://github.com/mini-kep/parser-rosstat-kep/blob/dev/src/kep/helper/path.py). Additionally the classes create subfolders if they are not present (I want this for unittest in temp directory), and there are methods for checking files exist and for reading their contents.

In your example, you can easily have root directory fixed in `setting.py`, 
but I think you can go a step forward with abstracting your data.

Currently `data_sample()` mixes file access and data transformations, not a great sign, and also uses a global name, another bad sign for a function. I suggest you may consider following:

```
# keep this in setting.py
def processed(filename):
   return os.path.join(DATA_DIR, filename)

# this works on a dataframe - your argument is a dataframe,
# and you return a dataframe
def transform_sample(df: pd.DataFrame, code=None) -> pd.DataFrame:
    # FIXME: what is `code`?
    if not code:
        code = random.choice(df.code.unique())
    return df[df.code == code].sort_values('Date')

# make a small but elegant pipeline of data transfomation
file_path = processed('my_data')
df0 = pd.read_parquet(file_path)
df = transform_sample(df0)
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are not committing lots of data and you make clear the difference between snapshots of the uncontrolled outside world and your own derived data (code + `raw`) == state. It is sometimes useful to use append-only-ish raw and think about symlinking steps like `raw/interesting_source/2018.csv.gz -> raw_appendonly/interesting_source/2018.csv.gz.20180401T12:34:01` or some similar pattern to establish a "use latest" input structure. Try to clearly separate config settings (`my_project/__init__.py`, `config.py`, `settings.py` or whatever) that might need to be changed depending on env (imagine swapping out fs for blobstore or whatever). setup.py is usually at the top level `my_project/setup.py` and anything related to runnable stuff (not docs, examples not sure) in `my_project/my_project`. Define one `_mydir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))` in one place (`config.py`) and rely on that to avoid refactoring pain.

Answer (score 0):

No, the use of a settings.py is only common practice if you are using Django.  As far as referencing the data directory this way, it depends on if you want users to be able to ever change this value.  The way you have it set up to change the value requires editing of the settings.py file.  If you want users to have a default but also be able to easily change it as they use your function, just create the base path value inline and make it the default in the def data_sample(..., datadir=filepath):.

Answer (score 0):

You can open a file by using `open()` and save it in a variable and keep using the variable wherever u wish to refer to the file.

```
with open('Test.txt','r') as f:
```

or

```
f=open('Test.txt','r')
```

and use `f` to refer to the file.
If you want the file to be both readable & writable, you can use `r+` in place of `r`.